# NRVO of std::array in constructor initialiser list

Tags: c++, constructor, stdarray, return-value-optimization

I know `std::array` doesn't do move semantics because it's not dynamically allocated. Do Compilers do proper NRVO for it? What about in the context of the calling code being a constructor initializer list?

Code is below and on goldbolt here: https://godbolt.org/z/je1Mvj15P
NB The share link passes `argv[1] = "12345678901234567890"`. Also it is using only -Og to keep the assembly readable. At -O3 it starts unrolling loops etc, but this does not affect the question I believe.

The constructor init list call `arr_(get_arr(s))` has no choice but to copy, because move its not available. Unless the compiler is doing full NRVO (which is "not mandatory", see comments below).

The compiler explorer output seems to show no copying to my eyes.

Is NRVO saving this?
Is this idiomatic / good? Or is `std::array` the wrong choice here? Or maybe this way of initialising an non-movable aggregate member with a function call and therefore relying on RVO is not sensible/reliable?

Would it be better to leave `arr_` uninitialised in the constructor init list and move the code from `get_arr` into the constructor body?  Like this: https://godbolt.org/z/jxv69YvK3

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>

std::array<std::byte, 20> get_arr(const std::string& s) {
    std::array<std::byte, 20> a;
    // a silly proxy algorithm for the real thing
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), a.begin(), [](auto b) { return std::byte(unsigned(b) << 1U); });
    return a;
}

struct S {
    explicit S(const std::string& s) : arr_(get_arr(s)) {}
    std::array<std::byte, 20> arr_;
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char* argv[]) {
    // in reality we are reading about 600'000'000 strings  from a file
    S s(argv[1]);
    return static_cast<int>(s.arr_[19]);  // use it to avoid optimising away
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a single answer to that, unless someone from compiler implementations can answer. A profiler might be able to tell you whether the algorithm you use takes most time in the initialization of `arr` or if there's something else taking time (i.e. copy).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Doesn't c++17 and onwards guarantee RVO in many cases? What about for aggregates like `std::array`? what about when the calling code is a "constructor" initialising a member  in a constructor init list?

Comment: I don't see anything to RVO here. For the number of items you are storing, you should be using a std::deque

Comment: @Dúthomhas The RVO is required because the `arr_(get_arr(s))` "init constructor call" in the `S` "constructor initialiser list" cannot use a move constructor (as could happen for a `std::vector` or a `std::string`), because `std::array` has no move constructor. So therefore the only way copying can be avoided is via RVO. The assembly suggests that RVO is happening. Regarding `std:deque`: Why? For the collection of `S`s? We are not holding them in memory, that would explode the machine.

Comment: Indeed, C++17 mandates, RVO, but this is not RVO, this is named RVO - NRVO. Standard only mandates copy elision for RVO, not necessarily for NRVO. As far as I know, the new rules in C++17 apply mostly to temporaries, because the point of variable materialization can (and must) be moved to wherever the temporary is actually used. In this case, the array is needed in `get_arr` already, so it's up to the compiler if it will be able to follow the callstack and construct array in place or not. If assembly tells you that NRVO occurred - well, that's basically all can be said.

Comment: OK, yes NRVO That rings true with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision   (I am going to amend the question to make that clear)

So basicially I can't rely on it from the standard, but gcc 11.1 (or whatever) may actually do it. And in the real code (which is more complicated) it may fail to see its way through it. So basically I was right to be suspicious, and it may actually be copying this.  So what's a better solution? Leave `arr_` uninitialized in the constructor list and move the code from `get_arr` into the constructor body? Then there is zero question about copying?

Comment: Note the only differences in assembly for a similar `void get_arr2(std::array<std::byte, 20>* arr_out, const std::string& s);` definition are a single additional `mov` instruction related to the different calling convention, plus difference choices of which registers are used: https://godbolt.org/z/rrzhb5qba

Comment: Yeah. So it's doing the NVRO. But it's not guaranteed, so I think I am going to move the code into the constructor body. It doesn't need to be in a function, plus using the body is fine here, because it's not "double infantilising" here, because the array (if left uninitialised on constructor init list) is a simple movement down of the stack pointer I think.

Comment: Note that there are *two* “copies” here: from `a` into the return value (which *might* be elided by NRVO), and from there into `arr_` (which as of C++17 isn’t any kind of copy or move since the function call is a prvalue).